# Unable to add Hyper-v host in different domain

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, scvmm

I have a SCVMM2012SP1 server sitting on a dual homed host, this server has connectivity to both our BE and CORP facing networks. I am able to add hosts in DOMAIN1 but not from DOMAIN2.

The VM that is running SCVMM is joined to DOMAIN1, we have a trust (I'm not really sure what type) and am able to access shares to/from. I have queried ports 5985 and it is showing listening from DOMAIN2 to my SCVMM server so I know the port is good.

Any idea if this is possible? The error I receive when adding is:

```
Error (415)
```

Agent installation failed copying C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012\Virtual Machine Manager\agents\I386\3.1.6011.0\msiInstaller.exe to \hypervHost.domain2.com\ADMIN$\msiInstaller.exe.
The network path was not found

Recommended Action

Ensure hypervHost.domain2.com is online and not blocked by a firewall. 
 1. Ensure that file and printer sharing is enabled on hypervHost.domain2.com and it not blocked by a firewall. 
I have opened both required ports for the agent which are 443 and 5985, I have tested from the destination server to the source (SCVMM) and the port shows as listening.

2. Ensure that there is sufficient free space on the system volume. 
   Tons of space available.
3. Verify that the ADMIN$ share on hypervHost.domain2.com exists. If the ADMIN$ share does not exist, reboot hypervHost.domain2.com and then try the operation again. This share does exist, I am able to browse it using same credentials I am using to install agent.

Comment: So, given that there are 4 recommended action and you say nothing about having them done - what about you TRY them?

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to add that part. I have tried all the solutions provided, I will update the original question.

Comment: You mention browsing the share but have you checked that you can write to it with the same credentials?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that the credentials allow me to read/write

Answer (score 0):

Check out [KB2818420](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2818420). It mentions having to install the file server role and wants both WinRM and WMI opened on the source server firewall.

Hope this helps!